# selenium: chrome failed to start when using options

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I am trying to use selenium with chrome web driver. When I run it without the options it works fine:

```
>>>driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path)
```

but when I add options (loaded profile) like this:

```
>>> options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
>>> options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=%s' % chromeProfile)
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path,chrome_options=options)
```

it starts the browser window, which seems alive, but the command hangs until it finally declares:

```
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    WebDriverException: Message: u'unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)'
```

what could be causing this problem and how can I go about debugging it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK - figured it out. The problem seems to be that one profile cant be opened while trying to connect a webdriver to it. I copied the default profile to a new location, and now it works fine. I'll leave this here in case this is useful to anyone.